# Can't install VS Code extension

Tags: vscode-extensions

I am unable to install extensions for VS Code. It worked, than stopped working. I examined the network tab in developer tools from command pallete -> shared process, no errors. I am behind a firewall and proxy at work, but manually installing should work nonetheless.

In install.log I find "One or more extensions are for Visual Studio Code. Try installing them in Visual Studio Code." That is excactly what I have been trying, it seems that VSIX can't understand that this extension is indeed meant for VS Code. Tried many different extensions.

Update after running suggestion from answer: Seems there is a compability issue, just wish this had been shown in the IDE directly.

[image]

```
13.01.2022 10:25:01 - Searching for applicable products...
13.01.2022 10:25:01 - Found installed product - Global Location
13.01.2022 10:25:01 - Found installed product - Visual Studio Enterprise 2019
13.01.2022 10:25:01 - Found installed product - Visual Studio Professional 2022
13.01.2022 10:25:01 - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: One or more extensions are for Visual Studio Code. Try installing them in Visual Studio Code.
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableDataImpl(IInstallableExtension extension, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableData(String vsixPath, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.IsExtensionPack(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.ExpandExtensionPackToInstall(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to open the `.vsix` extention file with vscode itself. Or you can run the command below from cmd with the correct path

```
code --install-extension <path\to\extention>
```

Documentation here: https://vscode-docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extensions/install-extension/

I'm not sure what are you using for install, but that's trying to install the vscode extention to **Visual Studio Professional 2022** and **Visual Studio Enterprise 2019**. Keep in mind the **Visual Studio** is not the same as **Visual Studio Code**.

Comment: Thank you, I knew this, but your answer made me realize that somehow code was no longer on PATH. I added code to PATH and ran your suggestion. Seems there is a compability issue, wish VS Code had just stated this right in the IDE. Thanks mr.